# Appending Empty Queues

Tags: java

I'm working on a radix sort program that will be using queues as bins. I'm getting an error with the append method I'm using for the queues. When I try to run the program, I enter some words for input, and then I get an error when trying to run the bin sort part of the program. It gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at LinkedQueue.append<LinkedQueue.java:53>
  at RadixSort.main<RadixSort.java:31>
```

I first assumed that this was because the queue that I am appending to is empty, so I added an if statement in the append method to account for this. After I tested it in JUnit, it worked - I could append a queue to an empty queue, and all of the data values are in the right spots and could be dequeued in the right order. When I ran the program, it still wouldn't work. I then realized that some of the bins would be empty, and added a condition to the if statement to account for an empty queue being added to a queue. I tested this again in JUnit and it worked successfully. However the program still won't run - I get the same runtime error as above. I'm confused as to what I'm not taking into consideration here - where is the null value? Below I've included the code for the append method in my LinkedQueue ADT class. Also, I'm using nodes to connect the values - `.data` is the data value and `.next` points to the next node.

```
public void append(LinkedQueue<T> q){
  if(this.isEmpty()){
    this.enqueue(q.front.data);
    this.front.next = q.front.next;
    this.rear = q.rear;
  }else if(!this.isEmpty() && !q.isEmpty()){
    this.rear.next = q.front;
    this.rear = q.rear;
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

Also, this is the piece of code in radix sort which appends all the queue bins to the "master" queue (where the error is at RadixSort.java:31):

```
  for(int n=0;n<26;n++){
     masterq.append(bins[n]);
  }
```

This is a homework assignment so if you could just point me in the right direction that I can go to fix the issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `at LinkedQueue.append<LinkedQueue.java:53>` tells you the exact line where the exception happens (53 in this case). Check that line, and see if there are any possibilities than an object you are referring to is `null`. Running your code in the debugger might also help you find out exactly what is happening with your code at runtime.

Comment: Oh I see where I went wrong. In the first condition of the if statement I needed to clarify `if(this.isEmpty() && !q.isEmpty())`. Thanks for the help I knew it must've been something small I was missing!